# how can declare type for nodes in XmlElement

Tags: c#

how can declare type of node in XmlElement in XML ?

for example i wanna "age" will be Int32 and gender Boolean.
how can do this ?

```
    XmlElement age = doc.CreateElement("Age");
    XmlElement gender = doc.CreateElement("Gender");
```

Comment: checkout `Jon Skeets` post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405284/how-to-add-attributes-to-xml-using-xmldocument-in-c-sharp-net-cf-3-5

Answer (score 0):

`XML` is all about text you cannot do such thing in  XML if you want to force  the check of the  value  type you have to use [XSD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in order to validate your  XML

this article show how you can  do this

[`C# - XML Schema Validator`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8781/C-XML-Schema-Validator)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot specify what type the element has to be when creating it. You need to define a XML schema which will hold the information about what is allowed by your XML and what is not.

Here is a guide for XSD by microsoft:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc302086.aspx